# MPAndroidChart - LineChart with different colors based on values

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to make charts in my app. I need to create chart like the following one. I need gradient line on `LineChart` and it's color must be based on values. For example Red for high, Yellow for medium, Green for low.

[image]

As far as I tried I managed to get like the following.

[image]

I searched for a day to find a solution, but I can't find any solution. So if any of you know how to fix this or have any idea about this please do share with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Solution from [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167191/android-canvas-draw-a-line-graph-with-a-gradient-whose-color-depends-on-the-y) worked for me.

[image: _]

```
protected void drawCubicBezier(ILineDataSet dataSet) {
...
// Get screen coordinates for min Y value
MPPointD pixelForValues = trans.getPixelForValues(0, minDy);
minDy = (float) pixelForValues.y;
MPPointD.recycleInstance(pixelForValues);

// Get screen coordinates for max Y value
pixelForValues = trans.getPixelForValues(0, maxDy);
maxDy = (float) pixelForValues.y;
MPPointD.recycleInstance(pixelForValues);

// Get screen coordinates for 0 value
pixelForValues = trans.getPixelForValues(0, 0);
float zeroDy = (float) pixelForValues.y;
MPPointD.recycleInstance(pixelForValues);

float range = minDy - maxDy;
float zeroPointNormalized = Math.max((zeroDy - maxDy) / range, 0);

linearGradient = new LinearGradient(
        0, maxDy, 0, minDy,
        new int[]{Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE},
        new float[]{0, zeroPointNormalized, zeroPointNormalized, 1f},
        Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
paint.setShader(linearGradient);
...
mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(cubicPath, paint);
```

}

Comment: from where you invoked this method. can you share some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try [William Chart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart) and use this method:

```
int[] colors = { getResources().getColor(R.color.menu_text),
 getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white) };

float[] index = { 0, 1 };
dataset.setGradientFill(colors, index);
```

**Edit 1**: In [MPChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), You can use

```
Paint paint = mChart.getRenderer().getPaintRender();
            paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 40, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

Comment: Will give a try. Thanks.

Comment: It only fills the area under the line. I need the line to be gradient.